# Why some famous programs are always using print

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal

I've read somewhere, do not remember where now, that `echo` is a more efficient way of outputting data then `print`.

Why do many famous software packages and frameworks, like WordPress and Drupal, like print so much? Is there any special reason behind that, or just a habit?

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, so I don't know if this print vs. echo advice you're talking about is common knowledge or not, but I would be surprised if there's much difference. Where you likely will find a difference is with printf (I assume PHP supports this function), because it does so much more than a simple print does, it should only be used when it's needed.

Comment: That's very interesting. Upvote +1.

Comment: yeah,That's right,very interesting.Upvote!

Comment: I don't know why this was closed but, here. I used to use print when I started, but then this is. The main difference between the two: echo 'one', 'two'; perfectly legal; print 'one','two'; throws a parse error. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Now, with the above you will note that multiple echo statements are simple separated with a comma making them actually better than multiple echo or print calls or even concatenation using ".". Then there is the dreaded inline functions which themselves print strings. Eg. print 'line'.func().'Up';  this will cause func()'s output to come before the rest of the statement. You can break the statement up, but using commas with echo saves you all that headache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In all actuality, Echo and Print differ based on how they are structured. Print returns a value much like a normal function would. But despite common belief, Print is not a function, as we can see by the fact that it doesn’t require parenthesis to work (Not to be confused with Printf). Print and Echo are actually both called language constructs, although this isn’t to say that we can’t make Print act like a function.

You can find some more reference here :

http://www.learnphponline.com/php-basics/php-echo-vs-print

**Not entirely complete, though. Print can be used as part of complex constructs, such as**

```
($b) ? print “True” : print “False”;
```

whereas Echo cannot. Also, if you want to use error output (@print”Test”;) you cannot use echo.
Otherwise – good info.

Comment: why this line ($b) ? print “True” : print “False”; can not use echo?

Comment: @zhua : Because Echo does not return a value, while print does.

Comment: You can put echo at the left and it will work fine. Eg <pre>echo ($b) ? "True” : "False”;<pre> still the same thing. But yes, in certain complex situations where you need two different actions, you can't use echo.g. But yes, in certain complex situations where you need two different actions, you can't use echo.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) to support this claim. However, a key difference between the two is that `echo` does not return a value and `print` does. So one could make an argument that `echo` is therefore *more efficient*.

Checkout the [PHP Benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com/) for more information about `echo` vs `print` and other interesting comparisons.

In the end, such things boil down to personal convention. Whatever efficiency gained from using `echo` over `print` is more than likely trivial relative to other areas of the code.

Comment: the return value **is what makes the difference**

Comment: @Itay, makes a difference between the two - yes. Makes a difference in performance, I wouldn't draw that conclusion. There's an argument for storage of return values, frame stacks, etc. But I'm willing to believe that in PHP's case the underlying code for `echo` and `print` is identical. Especially since `print` *returns 1, always*

Answer (score 0):

In performance tests I have seen no difference in speed between `print` and `echo` in PHP so they are interchangeable. Really it's personal preference. In the wild I've seen strictly PHP programmers stick to `echo` and multi-lingual programmers (if that's a phrase) use either.

Answer (score 0):

Because you read those things on blogs who like to talk about micro-optimizations. You should avoid premature optimization at all costs because it is not worth the effort => You should google famous quote by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare. You should only tackle your low hanging fruit when you have performance problems and stop wasting your time reading blogs like that. The creator of PHP gave a couple of presentations how to do that =>
http://www.archive.org/details/simple_is_hard

By now it is a pretty old video, but still very good if you ask me.